# Debug android device via Bluetooth

Tags: android, eclipse, bluetooth

I'm having problem with my USB ports on my laptop (only 1 active and is used with the external mouse)

Is there an option to debug the apps on the device from eclipse via Bluetooth instead of the USB cable?

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[adbWireless](https://market.android.com/details?id=siir.es.adbWireless) allows you to use adb over a wireless connection. It doesn't provide a bluetooth interface, but maybe this could also solve your problem?

Comment: hi,the adbwireless only work with rooted phone.can you please give another software.

Comment: hey ..the link is not available now  . .Can u suggest any other link . .?